# Firebase Facebook Login ionic3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, facebook-login, angularfire2

i have problem with Facebook Firebase login i get an error message
i have implement this code

```
loginFacebook() {
   this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()).then(res => {
     console.log(res);
    })
 }
```

When I try to login i get this error message:

> facebook has detected musart isn t using a secure connection to transfer information

[image: error message]

Comment: i don't how to do it .i'm new to this

Comment: its a mobile app with ionicv3